# creating pairs of a {2,80} dimesion

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, string-manipulation

Suppose that:

```
y={{"11111010101010111111", "00010011110010001110001011", 
   "000011111110001111101100", "11000100111101110011", 
   "0011001000011101010111", "1110101110001010001110", 
   "00010001011101001100110", "001101011011001100111100", 
   "11011010111001101101", "10100000000001000011011", 
   "11000001001000101110", "101101110001010110000", 
   "00111000100101010010111", "110111101101100011100", 
   "101010010001101001100", "1101001000000001101011111", 
   "001110000110001001011011", "10011011100001110100011", 
   "01100000111001100100110", "111100001101100110001", 
   "100010001001110000111", "010100111101111010100", 
   "11110011101110000100", "111101011001111110000", 
   "1100001110001101001001", "10000011011100001100", 
   "010101110110001111110010", "11101010101100011001", 
   "0110000101101110000011", "11011010101011011000", 
   "10111001101001101011", "100110111000001111110010", 
   "10101011101100011010", "00111010011001100011110", 
   "011000010101001011101", "1111100001001111011011", 
   "010010110101010101010", "1001101011001001001000", 
   "11010001011010111000", "011101111111100011100", 
   "0110010111001011110000", "1110101100001100000011", 
   "00000101010000100000001011101000", "011101010001101100000", 
   "01111110100001011101010", "110100000101000101010", 
   "011011010011111011110", "0110101110000001111001100", 
   "11100000011010101100", "10001001001100010001", 
   "0010101110011001100010", "001011001101001101101000", 
   "1101100100001001111010", "1011010101001011101010", 
   "100011110101000011100", "000010011010111001011111", 
   "011110001101001110100", "01100011001001010100111", 
   "1100111011001001111011", "10100010101010101010", 
   "00111111100001101011011", "11110101001100010110", 
   "10011110001000100011", "00101000101001010111010", 
   "111001010001100100111", "111011010001010000100", 
   "11010001111111001000", "11100111011110110110", 
   "10000110011001101111", "00011111100011101101010", 
   "00000010000000101110010011", "111011011101000011001", 
   "0101011011101101111001", "1011001101001001100010", 
   "0011100100001110011110", "001011011010001010001000", 
   "000010111100101010011100", "011111000111011110000", 
   "0101011111001110011111", 
   "000111001011001010001000"}, {"10101111111010110110", 
   "11010111111111000100", "000010010011101000001100", 
   "10001101111100011110", "0101101001101100010011", 
   "11011110111111011110", "1011101110000001010101000", 
   "10010011011000001101", "11111101000000001110101010", 
   "0100111000001001101001", "1111101001001001011001", 
   "11000010111010100111", "110010101101101010000", 
   "110011011001000100010", "001101101010001000111100", 
   "10111000111101000010", "11010010001011000110", 
   "0100000111001001000000", "0000010001011101001101111", 
   "11001110101110110110", "00000011010010011110001000", 
   "010010000111010111001", "010100101111111010100", 
   "101101010000001001110001", "001000101011001101111010", 
   "00011001101001011011100", "110011100101011111110", 
   "1111111110001010011111", "011001000001110001010", 
   "011000101111100001100", "11001001001010110011", 
   "00101001110001100110001", "110101110101010010001", 
   "010011000101000101101", "0011110001001101111101", 
   "00011100011011111011001", "0011000001101000000101", 
   "000111010010100001101011110", "1110100010001000101010", 
   "1101101111001000000011", "00011100111101001101101", 
   "10101000101100001000", "1001000001001101011000", 
   "0000101000111001111100001", "10111011010001110010101", 
   "000000110100000101111010111", "11101111011000001101", 
   "111110110001111111101", "011110000001000100110", 
   "001010110011001011010111", "00000010100101001011100011", 
   "10010101101010001010", "000101000101001011110000", 
   "00111011010001001100100", "000001111110011001111101111", 
   "010101011011000010110", "0010001010011101001011", 
   "11011101101011010110", "1011011111001111011100", 
   "00011011111101101001111", "010001000111010011001", 
   "11111010011000101010", "00010111111111010010111", 
   "10110011101101110000", "110100100001000011010", 
   "10001011011011000100", "00011111111000000001010010000", 
   "11000011100001100101100", "0001111101111001110111000", 
   "00111001110101000110101", "011001101001000010010", 
   "1111101001001100000110", "011000011011111111011", 
   "10001101101011001001", "010001100101011110110", 
   "0000110110000101010000011", "0100101101101111001110", 
   "000100101010000000001010100001", "0111110101101001001101", 
   "10100101011011010100"}};
```

I am currently working on a genetic algorithm, and what I am trying to do is create "offsprings". So the crossoverLocation is what location to cut the string. Essentially what I am doing is taking `[[i,1]][[i,2]]` and join them together after the cut. I am not really sure how to explain it.
I have written the following code:

```
offSpring = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++,
 crossoverLocation = RandomInteger[{0, Min[StringLength[parentPopF]]}];
 
 firstChild = 
  StringJoin[StringTake[parentPopF[[i, 1]], crossoverLocation], 
   StringTake[
    parentPopF[[i, 2]], {crossoverLocation + 1, 
     StringLength[parentPopF[[i, 2]]]}]];
 
 secondChild = 
  StringJoin[StringTake[parentPopF[[i, 2]], crossoverLocation], 
   StringTake[
    parentPopF[[i, 1]], {crossoverLocation + 1, 
     StringLength[parentPopF[[i, 1]]]}]];
 
 AppendTo[offSpring, {firstChild, secondChild}]];
```

So currently this code outputs 4 values because it is not taking into consideration the `{78}` dimension. For example `[[i,3]][[i,4]]`, etc
I tried adding another `For` loop but it didn't seem to work. Is there a way to get the missing values?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say you want the crossover point at position cut=3:

```
cut = 3;
z = Flatten[{y[[1, Range[1, cut]]], y[[2, Range[cut + 1, Length[y[[2]]]]]]}];
```

The above takes the first cut elements from y[[1]] and the remaining elements from y[[2]]. Reverse the 1 and the 2 to do the opposite. You should probably make it into a function so you can have the column specification (1 and 2 in the above) as variables. For instance, to use the same two columns at different cut points you might define

```
z[cut_] := Flatten[{y[[1, Range[1, cut]]], y[[2, Range[cut + 1, Length[y[[2]]]]]]}];
```

Then you could call this to get 5 random cuts:

```
z[#] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, Length[y[[1]]]}, 5]
```

Here /@ is the short form for Map.

Comment: So, I would need to define a function and the run a for loop for get more of the answers?

Comment: In Mathematica you rarely need to run loops. For this case, an idiomatic approach would be to define a function (as suggested above) and then "Map" that function onto the data set, that is, onto all the pairs of columns of y and cut points that you want.

Comment: So to create a function of it, it would be `z[col_]:=Flatten[{y[[col, Range[col, cut]]], y[[2, Range[cut + col, Length[y[[2]]]]]]}];`.?